# xpath is not working <a class="btn btn-primary" style=" width:200px" href="patient_enrollment.php"> Patient Enrollment </a>

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am unable to make xpath for this link

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" style=" width:200px" href="patient_enrollment.php"> Patient Enrollment </a>
```

unable to make xpath and I want to click on patient enrollment button.

```
//a[@text = 'Patient Enrollment'].click();
```

Comment: Its just `text()` without `@`. But better to use `//a[normalize-space()='Patient Enrollment']` to ignore leading and tracing spaces

Comment: I try this and driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@text(), 'Patient Enrollment']")).click();

Comment: @user1904103, you can also try `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Patient Enrollment')).click();`

Comment: //a[text() = 'Patient Enrollment'].click(); but not working.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()= 'Patient Enrollment']"}
Comma
Session ID: 1d137dd8-a5d6-4309-a4e5-d249befb7c36
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[text()= 'Patient Enrollment']}
org.junit.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()= 'Patient Enrollment']"}

Comment: check if there is any frame present.. If their is a frame then you need to switch it over first

Comment: No there is no frame .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on `Patient Enrollment` link you can use this `xpath`:

```
"//a[@class='btn btn-primary'][contains(@href,'patient_enrollment.php')]"
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.